# Why aren't duplicate questions deleted?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Just out of curiosity - it seems that keeping around questions which are closed as duplicate makes sorting through older questions more cumbersome.  Any reason they are kept around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes people ask the same question in very different ways.  Duplicates act as signposts.  Often when I'm searching a site for a question, the top result isn't the question itself but a duplicate -- because I and that asker happened to use the same language.  So the duplicate leads me to the original, but I might not have found the original at all otherwise.  (For example, I found [this](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1900/undeleted-comments-of-deleted-posts#comment6473_1901) via a duplicate, not the original.)

Duplicates that aren't likely to serve that purpose -- ones that are cryptic, for example -- can be nominated for deletion.  But in general, it's better to err on the side of keeping them in my experience.

Comment: Relevant and canonical: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/