# Duplicates sticking around

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, deletions

Is there a reason why questions already marked as duplicates stick around forever? Why aren't they automatically deleted after a month of inactivity or some other, similar, time-frame?

Edit: I just realized that my question is a duplicate of [this](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1902/why-arent-duplicate-questions-deleted) one. Should this one be deleted?;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In many cases, due to their different phrasing, they help users to find an answer, as it can be read on [StackExchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled):

> **Should duplicates be deleted?**
>
> In general, no: most duplicates stay around. Having multiple copies of the same question with different wording is useful as search fodder, because people looking for an answer may use different wording too.
> Duplicates that are word-for-word copies or that are so poorly written that they are not useful may be deleted by users with sufficient privilege.